# How to make a image always render from its top to its bottom when being loaded after dynamically changing its src?

Tags: image, performance, dynamic, render

In the following first example, the static image renders from its top to its bottom when it is being loaded, as expected.

[First example](https://jsfiddle.net/IanY/rpc2qy0L/3/)

In the following second example, the image is a 1x1 blank gif at the start. However, after its `src` is dynamically changed to the `src` of the image used in the first example, it does not render at all until it is fully loaded.

[Second example](https://jsfiddle.net/IanY/rpc2qy0L/4/)

What's the cause of the inconsistency in the rendering in the two examples? And how to make the image in the second example render from its top to its bottom when it is being loaded like the image in the first example?

---

<sup>Attribution: [The source of the image in use](https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/test-image-large-4000-px-wide-56-mb-size).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Back in the dark days of dial-up, we used a trick of forcing images into cache by creating a new image object for any of the ones we would be transitioning to.

Example:

```
<script>
  var jupiterImg = new Image('images/jupiter.png');
  var saturnImg = new Image('images/saturn.png');
</script>
```

Do this early on, like in the head of your HTML, and you won't have to wait for images to load at all, so you won't care if it's top to bottom, left to right, or something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks. But my situation is that there are 50+ images and each image should be loaded only when requested.

Comment: Use CSS to hide it until image loading is complete? It's a thought.

Comment: CSS cannot prevent the loading of images. Never mind, I had solved my issue by inserting a whole `<img src="path/to/the/actual/image.png" alt="">` element instead of changing the `src` of an existing placeholder `<img src="path/to/the/pixel.gif" alt="">`. Therefore I'm not urgent to seek the answer of my question for now. Thanks for trying to help.